# Transit visa for the UK - Plane to Cruise

Tags: visas, uk, transit, cruising

I'm going on an Ocean Liner Cruise from Southampton to New York. I am an Indian citizen and I live in India. I have a valid US visa. I am planning to fly to Southampton a day before the cruise. My question is, do I need to take a visitor visa for the UK? I used the [online calculator](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) to see if I need a visa, and it says that I don't need one as long as I am traveling to the US. However, I'm not sure about two things:

- Will I be asked for a visa when boarding my flight to Southampton from Kochi?
- Will I be allowed to actually exit the airport to head to the Southampton port? I know that I will be allowed to stay within the airport, but will I actually be allowed to exit the airport and go to the port?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need a visa.

To reach the port in Southampton you will need to clear UK immigration. You are not eligible to transit the UK without a visa because you are not **arriving and departing by air**.

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-transit-without-visa-scheme

Since you’ll be going through UK border control but leaving the UK within 48 hours, you should apply for a Visitor in Transit visa https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Would a Transit Visa work for me or do I need to get a Standard Visa?

Comment: @Zo-Bro-23 Using the online tool you linked in your question, you need a Visitor in Transit visa